# Cannot add extension with name 'kotlin', as there is an extension already registered with that name

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Having both Gradle plugins gave me that error:

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("kotlin")
    kotlin("android")
}
```

just either one is fine

Why?

Are they same thing?

I know `kotlin("android")` is actually `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")` from the source code of /gradle-6.0.1/src/kotlin-dsl/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/KotlinDependencyExtensions.kt

but I know nothing about `id("kotlin")`

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android']
   > Cannot add extension with name 'kotlin', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
```

Comment: does my answer help? I actually ran into the same thing :D

Answer (score 2):

> In **build.gradle** we were using it like :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

> In **build.gradle.kts** it should be :

```
plugins {  
  id("kotlin-android") 
  id("kotlin-android-extensions")  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `id("kotlin")`, but you will need `id("com.android.application")`.

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
}
```

See [Kotlin's documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#targeting-android) regarding using Gradle with Android.

Note, that using Kotlin Script with Gradle is not full supported by the current stable version of Android Studio (3.6.*). See [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130226195).

The full support seems to start at 4.0 which is currently in Beta 3 (see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#kts-compat)).

Answer (score -1):

I got this error after I got a prompt to set up Kotlin in Android Studio. Undoing that change fixed it.